# Testing rate limiting rules in firewalld

Tags: linux, ssh, iptables, firewalld, rate-limiting

I want to rate limit ssh connections **per IP** to a server running firewalld.

Suppose my sshd listens on port 2222, and I want to limit ssh connections per IP to 3 per minute. I tried:

```
sudo firewall-cmd --add-rich-rule \
  'rule port port="2222" protocol="tcp" accept limit value="3/m"'
```

Then on another machine I ran:

```
ssh myserver echo hello; \
ssh myserver echo hello; \
ssh myserver echo hello; \
ssh myserver echo hello; \  # should fail, but actually logs in
ssh myserver echo hello     # should fail, but actually logs in
...
```

It logs in each time. There is no rate limiting.

Where is my mistake?

Comment: Ah about the test in the question anyway: it works 5 times in a row because the default bucket size to the limit match (iptables)/limit statement (nftables) is 5. It would have failed at the 6th. This is also a parameter not available in the rich rules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like this is [not](https://github.com/firewalld/firewalld/issues/70) yet possible using firewalld's "rich rules".

So I'm using regular iptables rules via firewalld's `direct` feature. (I'm using firewalld's iptables backend because docker doesn't work with nftables, yet.)

```bash
sudo firewall-cmd --add-port=2222/tcp   # remember to allow custom ssh port

sudo firewall-cmd --direct --add-rule ipv4 filter INPUT_direct 0 \
  -p tcp --dport 2222 \
  -m state --state NEW \
  -m recent --name ssh --set

sudo firewall-cmd --direct --add-rule ipv4 filter INPUT_direct 1 \
  -p tcp --dport 2222 \
  -m state --state NEW \
  -m recent --name ssh --update --seconds 61 --hitcount 4 --rttl \
  -j REJECT --reject-with tcp-reset

# ...and the same for ipv6
```

To test:

```bash
for i in {1..4}; do
  nc -z myserver 2222
  [ "$?" = 0 ] && echo "$i = success" || echo "$i = fail"
done

# 1 = success
# 2 = success
# 3 = success
# 4 = fail
```